# Como construir uma URL relativa de forma segura?

Tags: java, url

Um método recebe trechos de uma URL e precisa concatená-los de forma coerente, mas sem pressupor detalhes sobre cada um.

Exemplos:

```
http://server + /path + /resource.js   => http://server/path/resource.js
http://server/ + /path/ + /resource.js => http://server/path/resource.js        
http://server + path + resource.js     => http://server/path/resource.js
//server + path + resource.js          => //server/path/resource.js
```

Basicamente, a coerência está em deixar apenas uma barra `/` entre cada elemento e não alterar a estrutura da URL como um todo, como no último exemplo onde o protocolos permanece ausente.

A minha primeira abordagem foi simplesmente criar uma rotina que junta duas partes verificando as barras:

```java
String joinUrlSafely(final String s1, final String s2) {
    final boolean s1HasSlash = s1.endsWith("/");
    final boolean s2HasSlash = s2.startsWith("/");
    if (s1HasSlash && s2HasSlash) {
        return s1 + s2.substring(1); //os dois tem barra, remove uma
    } else if (!s1HasSlash && !s2HasSlash) {
        return s1 + "/" + s2; //nenhum tem barra, coloca uma
    } else {
        return s1 + d2; //um dos dois tem barra, deixa ela lá
    }
}
```

No entanto, não fiquei satisfeito e fica a pergunta:

> Existe alguma API no Java ou em alguma biblioteca comumente usada (Apache, Guava, ...) que faça isso de uma forma mais segura e padronizada? Algum tipo de `UrlBuilder`?

Comment: Não sei se há algo desse tipo, até porque como o seu código demonstra, é uma tarefa trivial. Aliás, eu faria algo muito parecido com o que você está fazendo.

Answer (score 1):

Podes usar a API do próprio Java:  `java.net.URI e java.net.URL`.

```
@Test
public void urlTest() throws URISyntaxException, MalformedURLException {
    String base = "http://server///";
    String p1 = "/path/";
    String r1 = "/resource.js";
    String newUri = concat(base, p1);

    assertEquals("http://server/path/", newUri);
    assertEquals("http://server/path/resource.js", concat(newUri, r1));

}
```

---

```
private String concat(String s1, String s2) throws URISyntaxException, MalformedURLException {
    URL url = new URL(s1);
    return new URL(url.getProtocol(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getFile()+s2).toURI().normalize().toString();
}
```

Da uma olhada neste [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26787332/4785114).
EDIT

Uma outra forma é concatenando sempre uma "/" antes de cada String e depois antes de retornar o valor remover os "/" duplicados com uma expressão regular. Assim economiza alguns ifs.

```
url.replaceAll("(?<!(http:|https:))[//]+", "/");
```

Comment: Dá pra fazer isso sem o protocolo? Isso é importante para referenciar resources de forma relativa ao protocolo (HTTP ou HTTPS).

Comment: @utluiz Deste jeito não. Faz assim: concatena tudo com "/", depois antes de retornar remove os "/" duplicados com uma expressão regular do tipo: .replaceAll("(?<!https:)\\/\\/", "/");

Comment: Interessante. Poderia acrescentar isso na sua resposta?

Comment: blz, mas vc viu se funciona? não tive tempo de testar.

Comment: Não testei, mas entendi a ideia principal. Só ainda não estou muito convencido de que a abordagem é "segura e padronizada" como mencionei na pergunta. Vou aguardar mais um pouco para ver se alguém mais tem alguma alternativa. De qualquer forma, obrigado pela resposta.